# Search in Android won't work; app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, okhttp

I'm trying to implement a searching option on my app that gets data from an online database. I have okhhtp3.jar and okio.jar in my libs folder. Whenever I input text into search field, the app crashes and closes. This is my code for Search:
`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.SearchView;


import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;


`public class Search extends Fragment {

    private SearchView searchField;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, container, false);
        this.searchField = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchView);


        // perform set on query text listener event
        this.searchField.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key&language=en-US&query="+query+"&page=1&include_adult=false";
                //URLUtil.isValidUrl(query);
                if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url) == true) {

                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream");
                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{}");
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).get().build();

                    try {
                        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                        //System.out.println(response.message());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                System.out.println(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // do something when text changes
                return false;
            }
        });

        this.searchField.getQuery();
        return rootView;
    }




}
```

Exceptions I'm getting:

```
04-15 08:33:18 E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
04-15 08:33:18 E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
04-15 08:33:18 E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:170)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:136)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:171)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)                                                                                    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)                                                                                    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)                                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63)                                                                                    at Search$1.onQueryTextSubmit(Search.java:46)                                                                                    at android.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1285)                                                                                    at android.widget.SearchView.-wrap8(SearchView.java)                                                                                    at android.widget.SearchView$6.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1262)                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6193)                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:6075)                                                                                    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:829)                                                                                    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2688)                                                                                    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9960)                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewPager.java:2761)                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1630)                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:405)                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1798)                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3021)                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:547)                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:319)                                                                                    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
at com.a
04-15 08:33:18 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-15 08:33:18 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: PID: 4675
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)                                                                                  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)                                                                                 at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Add the stacktrace to your question. YOu can find stacktrace in Logcat. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

[With an **async** call](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#asynchronous-get).

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    // TODO: Learn to implement this correctly
});
```

> I have okhhtp3.jar and okio.jar in my libs folder

Try using Gradle instead of jar files.

> ```
> compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:(insert latest version)'
> ```

Comment: Tried implementing your answer with async call, I'm not getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` anymore, although, now I'm getting                                                                          `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)`  I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` in my manifest file.

Comment: Okay, and googling those messages should be the first thing to do